# how to make multiple queries in PHP

Tags: php, sql, loops

im very new to this and have a very basic knowledge php and SQL this is my first website, please could some one help.

I currently have information being pulled from my database to my website, which is good.

however i want to run another couple of queries on the same html page one that will display a list of the latest 5 entries in the database and sort them by 'location_id' descending, the other will display a list of 5 entries and display them random every time the page refreshes. see my code below:

```
?php
    require "connect.php";
    $query =  "select * from location";
    $result = @mysql_query($query, $connection) 
    or die ("Unable to perform query<br>$query");
?>

<?php
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<?php echo $row['location_id'] ?>

?php } ?>
```

Also when i was experimenting trying to solve this myself, i duplicated the loop shown above in a different location, and it would not display anything, can sone one explain why?

Thanks Guys

Comment: @yes123 Because there are so many tutorials for beginners which don't even mention PDO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs reset,

```
 mysql_data_seek( $result, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

i have just seen the syntax.

i guess ";" is missing in

should be

```
<?php echo $row['location_id'] ; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the query to do this or

create a new query and result with different names and then when the page runs have it select one of the queries to run.

```
$query1 =  "select * from location";
$result1 = @mysql_query($query1, $connection); 
or die ("Unable to perform query<br>$query1");
```

resetting might be easier but this is an option too